# Insert values from matrix dataframe into another dataframe using indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I have pandas dataframe `df_matrix` with shape = (4, 5) (Actually it much much much bigger!). It has integer numbers as indexes over rows and columns.

df_matrix =

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | **92.576** | 94.269 | **108.308** | 140.394 | 155.421 |
| 1 | 117.490 | 104.356 | 104.952 | **131.331** | 144.203 |
| 2 | 115.405 | 112.536 | 112.069 | 116.328 | 136.226 |
| 3 | 164.047 | 148.946 | 133.204 | 122.235 | **141.075** |

`df_matrix` contains data, which I want to put into column `depth` of another dataframe `df_main`, according its `df_main['row_i']` and `df_main['col_i']` columns
So, expected result is like this:

df_main =

|  | datetime | latitude | longitude | row_i | col_i | depth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2013-05-29 00:39:44 | 51.708487 | 104.366131 | 0 | 0 | **92.576** |
| 1 | 2013-05-29 00:40:44 | 51.708268 | 104.362324 | 0 | 2 | **108.308** |
| 2 | 2013-05-29 00:41:44 | 51.708036 | 104.358530 | 1 | 3 | **133.331** |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 296448 | 2022-06-14 03:39:40 | 51.876903 | 105.520172 | 3 | 4 | **141.075** |

I decided it by `iterrows`:

```py
for index, row in df_main.iterrows():
    df_main.loc[index, 'depth'] = df_matrix.loc[row['row_i'], row['col_i']]
```

it takes a lot of time while handling 200000+ rows. I believe that pandas has appropriate method, may be `merge`, but i have no idea which one and how to use it.
Is there decision more pythonic (pandasonic)))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as well:

```
df_main['depth'] = df_matrix.to_numpy()[df_main['row_i'],df_main['col_i']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) will be efficient here but you can still try it :

```
df_main = (
    pd.merge(df_main,
             df_matrix.stack().rename("depth"),
             left_on=["row_i", "col_i"], right_index=True, how="left")
)
```

​
Output :

```
print(df_main)

                   datetime   latitude   longitude  row_i  col_i    depth
0       2013-05-29 00:39:44  51.708487  104.366131      0      0   92.576
1       2013-05-29 00:40:44  51.708268  104.362324      0      2  108.308
2       2013-05-29 00:41:44  51.708036  104.358530      1      3  131.331
296448  2022-06-14 03:39:40  51.876903  105.520172      3      4  141.075
```